# How to disable stretching of image in ImageView?

Tags: java, android

There are some ImageView and image for this view. ImageView is 100px/100px, but image is 50px/50px. I wouldn't like the image fills full space in ImageView, i.e. I want that the ImageView contains my image in center of ImageView without stretching. How can I do it?

UPDATE:
Sorry, I've made a mistake. My ImageView is 50px/50px, and my image is 100px/100px. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 3):

Add to your ImageView:

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

**Note** that in the Android Studio xml layout preview if you use the `android:background="@drawable/my_image"` you will still see your image streached (In run time it won't streach).
But if you still want to see your ImageView background (not streached) also in the IDE preview use `android:src="@drawable/my_image"` instead of background property.
(in any case the scaleType should be center)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `android:scaleType` attribute on your image view. If the image is bigger than your view, either use `centerInside` or one of the `fitXY`, `fitStart`, `fitEnd` options.

You have all the info you need on the Android developer documentation for the ImageView class.

Comment: Please, look at my updated question. It means the following thing: now my image bigger then my ImageView and ImageView stretches

Answer (score 0):

set the `android:scaleType` with proper value, you can give `centerCrop`.

e.g. `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Answer (score 0):

In ImageView we have a property called scaleType that is shown below in the code.

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp"

    android:scaleType="center"

    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

It will not scale your image.